# Calling the function doesn't work

Tags: matlab, function, compiler-errors

I have a cell array of stucts, each containing the personalia of a person. I put it into this function to get them listed in a text file of a chosen name.

```
function store( filename, persons )

fid = fopen(filename,'w');

for i=1:length(persons)

    fprintf(fid, '%s',serialize_person(persons{i}));
end
```

Now this function works fine: I enter a <1x3 cell> and get out a text file with three listed persons. However, I want to call this function from another:

```
function process_store()

list=input('Write in the list of persons you want listed: ');
fprintf('\n')
newfile=input('Give the text file a name: ','s');

store(filename,list)
end
```

Here I enter the name of the <1x3 cell> as before, but I get a error message "Error using input,Undefined function or variable 'persons'."
Why is this? Am I not using the exact same data as Im using in 'store'?

Comment: So... is `persons` an array of `structs` or not? Because `list` certainly isn't.

Comment: Persons is an array of structs. Which I give as an input to list, so list=persons. Right?

Comment: list is defined in a input( ) command, not a input( ,'s') command. So if he puts braces list would be a cell.

Comment: at what line do you get the said error message ?

Comment: You forgot to close the file descriptor. But this is not causing that error message.

Comment: I get the error message in the third line of process_store

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the variable `persons` isn't accessible inside the function `process_store`. In Matlab (and most other programming languages) functions can't access variables defined in their calling functions. To understand this better, I recommend having a read of the Wikipedia article on [levels of scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29).

You essentially have two options here:

1. Make `persons` a global variable, both in your workspace and in the function `process_store`, by using the declaration `global persons`. I wouldn't recommend this.
2. Use the function `evalin` to allow `process_store` to access variables in its parent workspace.

I'd go with option 2 if I were you. It's a little tricky, so let me explain how it works. Let's create a variable `persons` in the global workspace.

```
>> persons = {'John', 'Jack', 'Jill'};
```

Now say we have the following function

```
function example()
    x = input('Give me a variable name: ');
    disp(x)
end
```

What happens if we try to use it?

```
>> example()
Give me a variable name: persons
Error using input
Undefined function of variable 'persons'
Error in example (line 2)
    x  = input('Give me a variable name: ');
```

Oh dear. That's because the function `example` doesn't have access to the global workspace, which is where `persons` is defined. But instead, we can store the name of the variable we want to access, and then check out its value in the global workspace by using `evalin`, like this

```
function example()
    s = input('Give me a variable name: ', 's');
    x = evalin('caller', s);
    disp(x)
end
```

Now if we use it:

```
>> example()
Give me a variable name: persons
    'John'   'Jack'   'Jill'
```

It works as we expected! Great!

#### Massive disclaimer

There is almost never a good reason to use functions like `evalin` (or `eval`, or `assignin` or any other function that messes around executing strings as code). There's almost certainly a better way of doing what you want to do. But without knowing what it is you're trying to do, it's hard to give you better advice.

Answer (score 1):

At the prompt

```
Write in the list of persons you want listed:
```

if you typed

```
persons
```

then you would get exactly that error message if the variable persons was not defined.